# Drawing Capital Market Line and Efficient Frontier

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, tikz-pic

I am struggling to produce the diagram shown in the picture below:
[image]
How do I reproduce it? So far my trial yielded an awful result. Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}



\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            height=10cm, width=12cm,
            axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left,
            xlabel = Volatility (standard deviation), ylabel = Expected Return,
            ymin=0, ymax=15, xmin=0, xmax=40,
            extra x ticks={65}, extra x tick labels={$\sigma$},
            extra x tick style={major tick length=0mm, grid=none},
            extra y ticks={25}, extra y tick 
            ,
            extra y tick style={major tick length=0mm, grid=none},
            enlargelimits=true,
            scatter/classes={
                a={mark=o,draw=black, mark size = 3pt},
                b={mark=*, mark size = 3pt,draw=red, fill = red},
                c={mark=*, mark size = 3pt,draw=black, fill = green}
            }
            ]
            
            \addplot[scatter,only marks, scatter src=explicit symbolic]
            coordinates {
                (14, 4)     [c]
                (17, 3)     [c]
                (18, 6)     [c]
                (23, 22)    [c]
                (28, 5)    [c]
                (37, 3)    [c]
                (29, 13)    [c]
                (32, 10)    [c]
                (38, 8.5)    [c]
                (35, 14)    [c]
                (15, 8)     [b]
            };
            \node at (axis cs:14, 4) [anchor=north west] {MacDonalds};
            \node at (axis cs:17,3) [anchor=north west] {Walmart};
            \node at (axis cs:18,6) [anchor=north west] {IBM};
            \node at (axis cs:23,22) [anchor=north west] {Nike};
            \node at (axis cs:28,5) [anchor=north west] {Molson-Coors};
            \node at (axis cs:37,3) [anchor=north west] {Newmont Mining};
            \node at (axis cs:29,13) [anchor=north west] {GE};
            \node at (axis cs:32,10) [anchor=north west] {Apple};
            \node at (axis cs:38,8.5) [anchor=north west] {Amazon};
            \node at (axis cs:35,14) [anchor=north west] {Tiffany};
            \addplot[red, very thick,  domain=-1:2.5, samples=200, variable=\t](
            {(20^2*t^2 + 12^2*(1-t)^2)^(0.5) }, %{(t^2 * 20^2 + (1-t)^2 * 12)},
            {11 * t + (1-t) * 5}
            );
            \node[color=red] at (axis cs:30, 0) [anchor=south west] {\textbf{Efficient Frontier}};
            \addplot[black, very thick, domain=-10:50, samples=100, variable=\x](
            ({x}, {1 + .4666667 * x});
            \node[rotate = 25, color=black] at (axis cs:30, 15) [anchor=south west] {\textbf{Optimal CAL}};
            \node[pin={[pin edge={thick}, text width=3cm, pin distance=2cm]90:{{\centering Mean Variance Efficient Porfolio}}}] at (axis cs:15, 8) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need help reproducing the diagram in the picture I have provided. So far my trials have been yielding awful results. I would greatly appreciate if I can get some assistance. Thank you.

Comment: I will be happy to help, but I need to know what your question is!? What is causing you problems?

Comment: I'm struggling to connect the Capital Market Line and Efficient Frontier at the red point. Also some other parts of the tikzpicture suddenly disappear e.g the right part of the tikzpicture. Also, I'm getting package pgfkeys error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in your code does not pass through the red point, so I assume it is wrong and just add some other random curve.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=10cm, width=12cm,
axis lines=center,
xlabel=Volatility (standard deviation), ylabel=Expected Return,
xmin=0, xmax=40,
ymin=0, ymax=15,
enlargelimits=true,
node near coords style={font=\small, right=1pt},
]
\addplot[scatter, only marks, mark size=3pt, fill=green, point meta=explicit symbolic, nodes near coords]
coordinates {
(14, 4) [MacDonalds]
(17, 3) [Walmart]
(18, 6) [IBM]
(23, 22) [Nike]
(28, 5) [Molson-Coors]
(37, 3) [Newmont Mining]
(29, 13) [GE]
(32, 10) [Apple]
(38, 8.5) [Amazon]
(35, 14) [Tiffany]
};
\addplot[black, very thick, domain=-10:50, samples=2] {1+7/15*x};
\addplot[mark=*, mark size=3pt, red, forget plot] coordinates {(15,8)};
\draw[cyan, very thick] (13.5,0) to[out=135, in=-90, looseness=0.7] (9.5,3.5);
\draw[red, very thick] (9.5,3.5) to[out=90, in=-136, looseness=0.7] (15,8) to[out=44, in=-140, looseness=0.7] (37,17);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with point, a lines and a curve]